# Undetermined Coefficient Particular Form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can somebody explain to me why the guess for the particular solution of $y''+2y'-24y=16-(x+2)e^{4x}$ would be $A+ (Bx^2+Cx)e^{4x}$ instead of $A+(Bx+C)e^{4x}$?

According to the textbook I am using: a function, for example, $(9x-2)e^{5x}$ would have a particular form $(Ax+B)e^{5x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Perhaps my answer does not fully address your question, but you can also proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
y'' + 2y' - 24 y = 16 - (x + 2)e^{4x} & \Longleftrightarrow (y'' + 4y') - (6y' + 24y) = 16 - (x + 2)e^{4x}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y' + 4y)' - 6(y' + 4y) = 16 - (x + 2)e^{4x}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u' - 6u = 16 - (x + 2)e^{4x}
\end{align*}
where $u = y' + 4y$.

Based on such substitution, can you take it from here?